# Compile intermediate type specification for rank-3 ConstantArray[_,{_,_,_}]

Tags: compile, tensors

```
Compile[{}, ConstantArray[0, {1, 2, 3}], CompilationTarget -> "C"][]
```

yields
`CompiledFunction::cfte: Compiled expression {{{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}} should be a rank 2 tensor of machine-size integers.`
Trying to specify the correct type using

```
Compile[{}, ConstantArray[0, {1, 2, 3}], 
{{ConstantArray[_, {_, _, _}], _Integer, 3}}, CompilationTarget -> "C"][]
```

fails with the same error message.

What is wrong here, and how to fix it?

P.S.: `ConstantArray[ConstantArray[0, {2,3}], 1]` does work but is more of an ugly hack than a solution.

Mathematica 11.01 on MacOS X.

Comment: `ConstantArray` is not fully compilable, i.e. not compilable in all cases, see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions). Just use `Table[0, {1}, {2}, {3}]`?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Thanks, using `Internal\`CompileValues[ConstantArray]` as described there I get `{HoldPattern[
   ConstantArray[{System\`CompileDump\`type_, 
     System\`CompileDump\`rank_}, {Integer, 
     System\`CompileDump\`drank_}]] :> 
  Internal\`CompileTypeEvaluate[{System\`CompileDump\`type, 
    System\`CompileDump\`rank + 
     If[System\`CompileDump\`drank > 0, 2, 1]}]}` which seems to explain the error. Do you know why the type specification did not work? I can use the table.

Comment: I don't know, but I think that _Mathematica_ simply does not have a rule to compile `ConstantArray[_, {_, _, _}]` even though you have specified the type, that is all. It still calls `MainEvaluate` after all.

Comment: How about `f := ConstantArray[0, {1, 2, 3}];

Compile[{}, f, {{f, _Integer, 3}}, CompilationTarget -> "C"][]`?

Comment: @xzczd, nice work-around for the type error. It still calls `MainEvaluate` though (as I assume you know, but maybe other readers do not), so if speed is the goal of compiling then one should be aware of that.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Yeah, if one aims at speed, then the solution in your first comment is probably the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't use `ConstantArray` inside compile. Alternatives that are fully compilable are

```
Compile[{}, Table[0, {1}, {2}, {3}], CompilationTarget -> "C"][]
```

or

```
Compile[{}, Array[0 &, {1, 2, 3}], CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

If you want to inject a static array into the compiled body, you can use

```
With[{arr = ConstantArray[0, {1, 2, 3}]},
 Compile[{}, arr, CompilationTarget -> "C"][]
]
```

In general, your question is too vague to tell what approach is appropriate in your case.